# Saving variables in a text file

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to load and save variables into a file.
For example:

```
@echo off
set /a number=1
echo %number%>text.txt
```

How do I store the number from the text file in a variable for example `variable1`?

Comment: Two possibilities: 1. [`set /P`](http://ss64.com/nt/set.html), together with [input redirection `<`](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirect.html); 2. [`for /F`](http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html)...

Comment: An easy way to write it out to a batch file like `set myvar=whatever` then `call` the batch file to load them.

Comment: Do you want to store the variable with another variable name in the text file? Or call back the number as a variable?

Comment: Finally, after 3 days.. But I was sure that I closed the else block after the `call %~dp0\lang\latvian.bat` line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code will lead to problem, better change to:

```
@echo off
set /a number=1
>text.txt echo %number%
```

Another way of the last line is:

```
echo %number% 1>text.txt
```

`1` means `STDOUT`, that's why your code won't write 1 to the file `text.txt`.

And to read the file into `variable1`:

```
set /p variable1=<text.txt
```

Note when there're multiple lines in the file, only first line will be read into the `variable1`.

From comment, and changed a little bit:

```
if not exist "%~dp0settings.gsf" ( 
    echo.>"%~dp0settings.gsf" 
    goto :createsave 
) else ( 
    echo Reading your savefile... 
    set /p lang=<settings.gsf
)
```

`%~dp0` will end with `\`, so no need to add another `\`.
You should close the `else` block, and it's better to indent and put `) else (` in a single line.
Try change according this, see if it works.
 -- Indentation is good for readability and debugging, in other programming languages too.

Comment: to read multiple lines, `( set /p var1= set /p var2= … set /p varn= )<text.txt`

Comment: I've deleted a bunch of tangential discussion in the comments. If you want to answer the question, post an answer. If you want to show code, edit the question.

Answer (score 6):

As [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54853179/saving-variables-in-a-text-file#comment96480355_54853179) by aschipfl, there are two ways to do it:

1. Using `set /P` (redirect variable to a text file and read (the file) with `set /p`).
2. Parse the file using a `for /F` loop.

As the first way is already [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54853474) by Tiw, I will only deal with the second one. You should do:

```bat
@echo off
set "number=1"
(echo %number%)>text.txt
for /F "delims= eol=" %%A IN (text.txt) do set "variable1=%%A"
```

Note that:

- `/a` option in `set` is used **only** to perform arithmetic operations. It doesn't mean that the interpreter will 'see' this as a number.
- The parentheses are added for security. They prevent `echo`ing an extra space in the txt file. `echo %number%>txt` won't work **if `%number%` is <10** because `0` is STDIN, `1` is STDOUT, `2` is STDERR and numbers from `3` to `9` are undefined. Apparently, it's sending STDIN/STDOUT/STDERR/UNDEFINED of nothing to a file.

Further reading:

- https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html
- https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html
- https://ss64.com/nt/set.html

Comment: @double-beep I mean when the file has multiple lines, in this case yeah it's safe to do so.

Comment: If the `%number%` is a word? For example: `example1`? Does that change anything?